Does $xJxJ\in\langle N,e_{B}\rangle$?
Let $B$ be a von Neumann subalgebra of a finite von Neumann algebra $N$ with a faithful normal trace $\tau$ and let $J$ be the conjugate linear operator on $L^{2}(N)$ defined by $J(x)=x^{*}$ for $x\in N$. On the bottom of page $70$ of Finite von Neumann Algebras and Masas, the authors claim that $uJuJ\in\langle N,e_{B}\rangle$ when $u\in\mathcal{N}(B)$. I don't see why this is the case. Is it a general fact that $xJxJ\in\langle N,e_{B}\rangle$? I know that $JxJ\in N^{'}$, but I don't see why this follows, even if we assume that $xJxJ$ commutes with $e_{B}$.


Unless I’m misunderstanding something, the claim is false. Recall that $\langle N, e_B \rangle’ = JBJ$. (Indeed, $\langle N, e_B \rangle’ = N’ \cap \{e_B\}’ = JNJ \cap \{e_B\}’$. And for $x \in N$, $JxJe_B = e_BJxJ$ iff, for all $y \in N$, we have $E_B(y)x^\ast = JxJe_B(y) = e_BJxJ(y) = E_B(yx^\ast)$, iff $x \in B$.) Thus, $uJuJ \in \langle N, e_B \rangle$ iff it commutes with $Jx^\ast J$ for all $x \in B$. But then, for any $y \in N$,
$$uyu^\ast uxu^\ast = uyxu^\ast = uJuJJx^\ast J(y) = Jx^\ast JuJuJ(y) = uyu^\ast x$$
So this happens for all $x \in B$ and $y \in N$ (i.e., $uJuJ \in \langle N, e_B \rangle$) iff $uxu^\ast = x$ for all $x \in B$, i.e., iff $u \in B’ \cap N$. Of course, $\mathcal{N}(B)$ is in general far larger than the unitary group of $B’ \cap N$.

That looks correct to me.

@SihOASHoihd Yeah, I’m not sure why the author claimed this. (Is there any more clarification you need or follow-up question you want to ask? Otherwise, if you find the answer satisfactory you can accept it.)

The next line is "the converse also holds so that $\mathcal{N}(B)={u\in\mathcal{U}(N):uJuJ\in J\langle B,e_{B}\rangle^{'}J}={u\in\mathcal{U}(N):uJuJ\in\langle B,e_{B}\rangle^{'}\cap J\langle B,e_{B}\rangle^{'}J}$". I guess my only other question would be, given that the previous line is false, does that mean this statement is also false?

@SihOASHoihd My answer is an if and only if, i.e., for a unitary $u \in N$, $uJuJ \in \langle N, e_B \rangle$ iff $u \in B’ \cap N$. As $\mathcal{U}(B’ \cap N) \subset \mathcal{N}(B)$, the “converse”, if understood as the claim that $uJuJ \in J\langle B, e_N \rangle’J$ implies $u \in \mathcal{N}(B)$, is technically true, as $J\langle B, e_N \rangle’J \subset \langle N, e_B \rangle$. But the equality that $\mathcal{N}(B) = {u \in \mathcal{U}(N): uJuJ \in J\langle B, e_B \rangle’J}$ is false. (Unless $\mathcal{N}(B) = \mathcal{U}(B’ \cap N)$, which is not true in general.)
